# I list all available db files in a drop down how can I pass the file name into a connection string

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu, connection-string

Question is I list all available access db files in a drop down how can I pass the file name into a connection string? Any help would be greatly appreciated

example here is my form1 code

```
    #region Form1 constructor
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        var filenames = from fullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\Users\jsnow\Desktop", "*.mdb")
                        select Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
        foreach (var filename in filenames)
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add(filename);
        }
        string whatFile = comboBox3.Text.ToString();

        // Here is where I want to pass the file name into my connection string so for my source it will be the string whatFile.

        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= + whatFile";
        try
        {
            database = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            database.Open();
            string queryString = "SELECT FileNumber, DueDate FROM Table1";
            loadDataGrid(queryString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: It's too early to pass, user have to select something first.

Comment: How would I go about doing that what would you suggest? @Sinatr

Comment: Dont even know which problem to comment, there are many. If you change the selection inside your combobox, it wont be switched on your `connectionString` because you've written everything procedual inside your `Form1()`. You are probably coming from writing console apps. You would've to create an event for the comboBox like `SelectedIndexChanged` or somethign like that.

Comment: According your question it could be a dirty `"Somestring" + someVar;' or the better way 'String.Format("Somestring{0}",someVar);'. This cant be fixed with a single step.

Comment: In constructor the form is not yet created nor shown. You can only fill combobox values at that time. Then sometimes later the form will be displayed. Much later the user will choose something in combobox and only **then** you can run the rest of your code which combines `ComboBox.Text` into connection string, opens database, etc. Don't try to do all this in constructor. Or maybe you want to use some default value to query that database and if user choose another database - then refill data by querying another.